Reproduce the behavior of noUncheckedIndexedAccess as a function
Can you reproduce the behavior of noUncheckedIndexedAccess as a function, with noUncheckedIndexedAccess disabled?
I want:
safeIndex({ x: 1 }, 'x') → number
safeIndex({ x: 1 }, 'y') → type error
safeIndex({ [key: string]: number }, 'x') → number | undefined


there are several ways to have the wanted result. what have you try ? where are you block ?

@jeremy-denis If there are several ways, could you kindly give me one? I've tried plenty of things, over quite some time. I'd rather not go over them if someone happens to know a way to solve this problem. Thanks.

to let us help and reply you we need a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example the idea is not to not give you the reply but give you element to understand the reply and growth in your skill

In case it helps, the closest I've gotten is:
const safeIndex: <T extends Record<string, number>> (obj: T, i: keyof T) => number | undefined = (obj, i) => obj[i];
const test: Record<string, number> = { y: 1 };

const a = safeIndex({ x: 1 }, 'x')!; // number
const b = safeIndex({ x: 1 }, 'y'); // error
const c = safeIndex(test, 'x'); // number | undefined

We use a generic function which takes a parameter which extends from Record<string, number> and receives two inputs, as your example. The second uses the keyof operator to enforce the limitation that it should belong to the keys of the first parameter.
The function then makes use of type inference in order to set the value of the generic parameter T. So when the first input is { x: 1 } TS knows that the only valid key is x, whereas if the input is of type Record<string, number> or { [key: string]: number } it will not enforce a specific key value because any string would be a valid key.
The hackish part is using the non-null assertion operator to make the type of a be of type number, otherwise it would be number | undefined.
